# Buscar dados de entity's para outra

Tags: javascript, jquery, symfony-2

Eu tenho um entity de Intervenção, outra de Avaria e outra de Prevista e eu queria ir bucar os dados dessas entity e juntar tudo numa tabela só.

A tabela que junta tudo vai estar dentro da entity Intervenção dentro de um ficheiro detalhes.html.

Tabela vai ser:
Intervenção: Data, Hora e Duração;
Avaria: Data, Descrição e Impedimento;
Prevista: COntagem, Duração, Fazer, Tempo e Ficha;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha tabela está assim:
   
      
         
            Operário
            Intervenção
            Avaria
            Prevista
         
         
            Id
            Identidade
            Data
            Hora
            Duração
            Data
            Descrição
            Impedimento
            Contagem
            Duração
            Fazer
            Tempo
            Ficha
         
      
      
         
            {% for entity in entities %}
                 
                 
                 {% if entity.data %}{{ entity.data|date('Y-m-d') }}{% endif %}
                 {% if entity.horainicio %}{{ entity.horainicio|date('H:i') }}{% endif %}
                 {{ entity.duracao }}
            {% endfor %}

Como eu consigo ir buscar os dados das outras entity para esta tabela?

Os relacionamentos entre elas existentes são:
Na Intervenção:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="intervencao")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
*/
private $maquina;
```

Na Avaria:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="avaria")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $maquina;
```

Na Prevista:

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="prevista")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
private $maquina;
```

No IntervencaoController:

```
/**
 * Lists all Intervencao entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="manutencao_intervencao")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities =$em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->findAll();
    $avarias = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Avaria')->findAll();
    $previstas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'avarias' => $avarias,
        'previstas' => $previstas,
    );
}
```

Comment: Qual é o relacionamento que as entities (`Intervencao`, `Avaria` e `Prevista`) possuem umas com as outras? ManyToOne, ManyToMany, OneToMany, OneToOne etc.

Comment: Na intevenção: /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina", inversedBy="intervencao")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="maquina_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    private $maquina;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No IntervencaoControl

```
 /**
 * Lists all Intervencao entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="manutencao_intervencao")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entities =$em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Intervencao')->findAll();
    $avarias = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Avaria')->findAll();
    $previstas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Prevista')->findAll();

    return array(
        'entities' => $entities,
        'avarias' => $avarias,
        'previstas' => $previstas,
    );
}
```

E no Intervencao.php

```
{% for entity in entities %}{% for avaria in avarias %}{% for prevista in previstas %}
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{% if entity.data %}{{ entity.data|date('Y-m-d') }}{% endif %}</td>
                        <td>{% if entity.horainicio %}{{ entity.horainicio|date('H:i') }}{% endif %}</td>
                        <td>{{ entity.duracao }}</td>
                        <td>{% if avaria.data %}{{ avaria.data|date('Y-m-d') }}{% endif %}</td>
                        <td>{{ avaria.descricao }}</td>
                        <td>{{ avaria.impeditiva }}</td>
                        <td>{{ prevista.contagem }}</td>
                        <td>{{ prevista.duracao }}</td>
                        <td>{{ prevista.fazer }}</td>
                        <td>{{ prevista.tempo }}</td>
                        <td>{{ prevista.ficha }}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu vi nos relacionamentos das suas entidades, você deve fazer o seguinte.

Primeiro busque todas as máquinas, uma vez que todas as outras entidades possuem relacionamento com ela, com a seguinte DQL:

```
SELECT m, i, a, p
FROM RoqSysManutencaoBundle:Maquina m
LEFT JOIN m.intervencoes i
LEFT JOIN m.avarias a
LEFT JOIN m.previstas p
```

Um problema nesse caso é que você não sabe quantas intervenções, avarias ou previstas uma máquina possui – então terá que desenhar sua tabela pensando nisso.

Depois que você passou os dados para a sua view, basta fazer um *loop* externo pelas máquinas e *loops* internos pelas avarias, intervenções e previstas:

```
{% for maquina in maquinas %}

Intervencoes:<br>
{% for intervencao in maquina.intervencoes %}
    {{ intervencao.data }}<br>
    {{ intervencao.duracao }}<br>
{% endfor %}

Avarias:<br>
{% for avaria in maquina.avarias %}
    {{ avaria.data }}<br>
    {{ avaria.descricao }}<br>
    {{ avaria.impedimento }}<br>
{% endfor %}

Previstas:<br>
{% for prevista in maquina.previstas %}
    {{ prevista.contagem }}<br>
    {{ prevista.duracao }}<br>
    {{ prevista.fazer }}<br>
    {{ prevista.tempo }}<br>
    {{ prevista.ficha }}<br>
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Edit: depois do seu complemento, vi o que você está fazendo de errado. Você está trazendo as coleções de entidades do tipo `Intervencao`, `Avaria` e `Prevista` separadas uma das outras e desvinculadas das máquinas. É mais interessante você trazer as máquinas com a DQL que sugeri acima e passá-las para a view da seguinte maneira:

```
/**
 * Lists all Intervencao entities.
 *
 * @Route("/", name="manutencao_intervencao")
 * @Method("GET")
 * @Template()
 */
public function indexAction() {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $maquinas = $em->getRepository('RoqSysControlManutencaoBundle:Maquina')->findAll();

    return array(
        'maquinas' => $maquinas
    );
}
```

Comment: Não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Que erro você está tendo?

Comment: Method "intervencoes" for object "Proxies\__CG__\RoqSys\Control\ManutencaoBundle\Entity\Maquina" does not exist in /var/www/roqsys/src/RoqSys/Control/ManutencaoBundle/Resources/views/Intervencao/index.html.twig at line 76  => é esta a linha {% for intervencao in maquina.intervencoes %}

Comment: Os relacionamentos que você criou entre as entidades são bidirecionais, correto? Isso é, existe o relacionamento da máquina para a intervenção e vice-versa. Se sim, você só precisa criar os métodos das entidades com o comando `app/console doctrine:generate:entities RoqSys`. Já o fez?

Comment: sim, fiz logo no inicio, se não tinham entities

Comment: Na verdade o comando gera os métodos das entidades contidos no namespace `RoqSys`. É por causa da inexistência dos métodos que você está tendo o erro que acusou acima.

Comment: @CatarinaSilvestre complementei a resposta.